# Migrating from Tomcat 6 JDK 1.6 to Tomcat 7 JDK 1.7 Session Issues

Tags: java, session, tomcat

We did a migration of our application which was functioning properly in Tomcat 6 with JDK 1.6 to Tomcat 7 JDK 1.7. The WAR deployed to the Tomcat 6 works properly in Tomcat 7.But the WAR compiled under JDK 1.7, causes the is that if we click any  links in the UI it immediately reports session timed out.
We are using MyFaces 2.0.7 with Trinidad 2.0.0.  Clicking a link gives a ViewExpiredException.

Problem may be associated with below stacktrace which appears during the start-up of the Tomcat 7 server.

Mar 11, 2014 5:31:26 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.InvalidObjectException: enum constant resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter does not exist in class javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$PropertyKeys
java.io.InvalidObjectException: enum constant resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter does not exist in class javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$PropertyKeys
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1741)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5476)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.PropertyKeys.resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1739)
    ... 43 more

Mar 11, 2014 5:31:26 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.InvalidObjectException: enum constant resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter does not exist in class javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$PropertyKeys
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1741)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5476)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.PropertyKeys.resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1739)
    ... 43 more

Mar 11, 2014 5:31:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

Comment: One additional note on this. If I set the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD param to 'client'. The app works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat tries to deserialize an existing session, but cannot do so as the serialization byte stream references an enum (resourceDependencyUniqueIdCounter) which it cannot find.

I would guess you either updated Tomcat inplace (keeping your old serialized sessions) or that you are still changing your classes a lot without changing the serial number in the class.

The simplest solution at this point is most likely to clean out the existing serialized session files and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the input. As I understand that, what I need to do is locate the .SER file in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\work\Catalina\localhost\<app>\ folder. This folder does not contain any files. Also, this is a separate install location from the previous Tomcat 6 install.